# Time pops up in a red box every minute in ubuntu 18.04 screen

Tags: 18.04

Every minute a red box with the time appears in my screen. When I change to any window or pass the cursor on the box it fades away. I am currently using ubuntu 18.04. I can't remove it. Please help.

Here's the photo of the red box:
[image: red box with time]

Comment: Have you installed tweaks or any extensions? and what happens if you set the wallpaper back to ambiance (default)

Comment: I have installed tweaks and a few extensions. I have: Activities configurator, **apt update indicator, cpu power manager, clipboard indicator**, dash to dock, frippery move clock, **hide activities button, lock keys, openweather, panel osd, places status indicator, refresh wifi connections, remove dropdown arrows, screenshot tool, status area horizontal spacing**, ubuntu appindicators and ubuntu dock. Ps: the extensions that are active in the moment are in bold. I tried changing the wallpaper back to ambiance and the problem continues.

Comment: Probably not the extensions, but it is easy to check: turn them all off and see whether the problem persists (after logging out and back in). Did you install Conky? If yes, then that might be it.